# Can Applicative Functors make async Tasks more effective?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, applicative

In [drboolean's gitbook](https://drboolean.gitbooks.io/mostly-adequate-guide/content/ch10.html#ships-in-bottles), there is an example explaining the prime situation where applicative functors pull their weight:

```
// Http.get :: String -> Task Error HTML
var renderPage = curry(function(destinations, events) { /* render page */  });

Task.of(renderPage).ap(Http.get('/destinations')).ap(Http.get('/events'))
// Task("<div>some page with dest and events</div>")
```

and it is said that:

> Both Http calls will happen instantly and renderPage will be called when both are resolved. Contrast this with the monadic version where one Task must finish before the next fires off.

I cannot understand it well. I think:

Task.of(renderPage).ap(Http.get('/destinations')).ap(Http.get('/events')) is just (Http.get('/events')).map(Http.get('/destinations').map(renderPage)), does Both Http calls will happen instantly instead of that one Task must finish before the next fires off?

Comment: I don't know Folktale's `Task` but usually the applicative in the context of  asynchronous computations runs "in parallel", because the next computation doesn't depend on the result of the previous one. When you look at `then` chains (which are similar to monadic chains), it is sequential and the reason why there is a specific `Promise.all` method.